# The privileges are broken with cluster and context set

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts

If you set the cluster information by get-credentials, kubectl will not allow you to connect to information such as pods.
It is a kubernetes API access from within the pod, and the mounted service account has a ClusterRole of RBAC cluster-admin.

First of all, right after the POD is activated, it is normal.

```
foo@abcd:~$ kubectl get po
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx      2/2     Running   0          27h
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy        1/1     Running   0          27h
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz          1/1     Running   0          18m
```

In this case, the cluster and context are not set.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: null
contexts:
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: gke_prj_zone_cluster-name
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: xxxxxx
        expiry: "2020-10-03T04:29:36.29112618+09:00"
      name: gcp
```

Next, set the cluster information.

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-name --zone zone --project prj
```

Look at the settings again.

```
foo@bar:~$ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://12.34.56.78
  name: gke_prj_zone_cluster-name
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: gke_prj_zone_cluster-name
    user: gke_prj_zone_cluster-name
  name: gke_prj_zone_cluster-name
current-context: gke_prj_zone_cluster-name
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: gke_prj_zone_cluster-name
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config: null
      name: gcp
```

Then my authority is gone.

```
foo@bar:~$ kubectl get po
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "123456789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default": requires one of ["container.pods.list"] permission(s).
```

Why would they lose their authority?

========================
Because of the operation on the gke pod, I didn't get the credentials first, I just attached the cluster-role (cluster-admin) to gke.

with helmfile

```yaml
{{- if .Values.serviceAccount.create -}}
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: {{ include "serviceAccountName" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "labels" . | nindent 4 }}
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: {{ include "serviceAccountName" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Can you show all the command that you use, from the beginning. I don't know how did you obtain the first credential.

Comment: Because of the operation on the gke pod, I didn't get the credentials first, I just attached the cluster-role (cluster-admin) to gke. [postscript]

Comment: Could it be that a service account mounted on pod only has operational privileges to the current cluster from the beginning?
If so, can't I have access to all the clusters from inside the pod? The service account created by terraform with `gcloud auth` was authenticated as the default service account and could not get container, even if it was connected to kubernetes API.

Comment: I was able to connect to it by copying ~/.kube/config, which is used locally, into the POD and doing `kubectl get po --kubeconfig=copied-conf`. The problem seems to be in the kubeconfig in the POD. Is there an easy way to get this configuration in?

Comment: But, the kubeconf configuration has a short deadline and I want to automatically capture this configuration easily. `gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${cluster-name} --zone ${zone} --project ${prj}` I wonder why auth-provider is largely missing in the credential that I get be possible

Comment: Hello. Do I understand correctly that you want to access the Kubernetes `API` from a `GKE` pod? Could you share the exact steps you followed to get to this point?